# Javascript AMD Modules: How to get Visual Studio intellisense across modules

Tags: intellisense, requirejs, js-amd

After looking into Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) in the javascript context I was wondering how to get intellisense in Visual Studio 2010 for a dependent module.

For example given module A:

```
define(function() {
    return {
        square: function(value) {
            return value * value;
        }
    };
});
```

and a corresponding module B:

```
define(["A"], function(a) {
    return {
        value: a.square(10)
    }
});
```

Then I would like to have full intellisense for the module A (represented as parameter a) within module B. Note that both of these modules would be defined in separate files (A.js and B.js in this case).

Comment: I have posted a bug for visual studio for a similar issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2825862 (It didn't understande my login when I posted though). If similar conditions fixes your issue, please comment the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the author of RequireJS is working on Intellisense support here:
https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs-intellisense

Unfortunately I haven't gotten the "magic" to work yet.

**Update**: I did get this to work in certain scenarios. In particular it works great when all of the js files are in the same folder.

Comment: I placed all of the javascript files in the same folder and "referenced" require.js (drag the file to the editor to get a reference comment). I found that it usually takes a few seconds to start working. I did get it to work for some other folder structures but it seemed pretty limited. Also I think it only works for require calls (not defines).

Comment: I get the define and require functions (i.e. 'require' shows up in intellisense within the default module definition). However I cannot get intellisense for test or person, i.e. the 'test.' doesn't list the numberProperty and childObject. This is what I meant by 'full' intellisense.

Comment: Got it working, here's what I did:

1. Cloned https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs-intellisense
2. Created an empty web app sln in vs 11 (vs 10 doesn't work for me)
3. Copied all js files from test into sln
4. Opened default.js and removed 'js/' prefix (person and test are not in a subpath)
5. Added "/// <reference path="require.intellisense.js" />" to the top of default.js
6. The person parm should now have intellisense
7. Opened test.js and added empty dependency array, i.e. define should now be "define([], function () {"
8. The test param, in default.js now has intellisense, yay :D

Answer (score 5):

This comment here helped me get it to partially work: [Comment on GitHub Repo](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs-intellisense/commit/c214216e5eece2114f42c513e46f604d33699184#commitcomment-1732386)

Basically, I had to make sure that this:

```
/// <reference path="require.js" />
```

is at the top of the _references.js file.  It works in 'require' and 'define' blocks, but doesn't seem to work inside of anonymous functions within 'define' blocks.